# setTimeout macrotask in the UI event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-loop

i wrote following simple react component

in the onBlur event handler, i create a new macrotask by setTimeout

```
function App() {
  const onBlur=()=>{
    console.log('onBlur')
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('setTimeout')
    }, 0);
  }

  const onClick=()=>{
    console.log('onClick')
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div id="first" onClick={onClick}>aaa</div>
      <div id="second" contentEditable onBlur={onBlur} suppressContentEditableWarning>qq</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and then

1、i move the mouse pointer into second div

2、then i click the first div

it print out with following sequence in the console

onBlur

setTimeout

onClick

my question is why setTimeout displays before onClick;

apprecaite your answers; please help me; thank you very much;

Comment: because it triggers automatically on onBlur but you need click on `onClick` manualy, which is slower then some microseconds

Comment: Change `setTimeout(..., 0)` to `setTimeout(..., 10000)` and you should be able to click before the setTimeout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the blur event is fired from the `mousedown` event, while the `click` event is made of both `mousedown` and `mouseup`.

```js
const d1 = document.querySelector("div");
const d2 = document.querySelector("div[contenteditable]");

d1.addEventListener("mousedown", ({type}) => { 
  console.log(type);
  setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout from %s", type), 0);
});
d1.addEventListener("click", ({type}) => console.log(type));
d1.addEventListener("mouseup", ({type}) => console.log(type));
d2.addEventListener("blur", ({type}) => {
  console.log(type);
  setTimeout(() => console.log("timeout from %s", type), 0);
});
d2.focus();

/* expected output:
mousedown
blur
timeout from mousedown
timeout from blur
mouseup
click
*/
```

```html
<div>CLICK ME</div>
<div contenteditable>focused element</div>
```

So by the time you release your mouse pointer, the blur event has already been fired and the `0` timeout also had time to get executed, unless if you can do so in less than one ms in Chrome, where they have a 1ms minimum timeout.

Comment: thank you for your answers, would you please check my another problem , hope for your reply 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71336323/receive-unexpected-response-when-click-react-virtualized-list-item

Comment: @YaoTao I saw your other question, sorry I can't answer it.

Comment: you have already help me very much! thanks anyway !